# Detectar en una imagen si dos puntos están unidos

Tags: python, matplotlib, cv2

estoy tratando de crear un algoritmo para crear el camino para llegar del punto A al punto B en un laberinto, pero quisiera saber si existe una forma via CV2 o alguna libreria que detecte si dos puntos de un color especifico están unidos por una linea de otro color.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mapa completo, donde las lineas verdes son una matriz que muestra el esqueleto del laberinto original, mientras que los puntos azules son otra matriz que muestra las esquinas del esqueleto del laberinto.

Me gustaría saber si hay algun procedimiento que detecte si un punto (A) está unido otro punto (B), mediante la linea verde como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo tanto las matrices del esqueleto del laberinto, las esquinas del esqueleto del laberinto y el laberinto original separadas como una sola imagen con todos estos elementos unidos como se mostro en la primera imagen del post.

¡Gracias a todos los que lean este post y espero que pasen un buen día!

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue cerrada. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/549712/detectar-si-dos-puntos-est%c3%a1n-unidos-por-una-linea-en-una-imagen

Comment: Fue cerrada porque no estaba en el idioma correcto, y no la volvieron a abrir desde que corregí el problema.

Comment: Lo recomendable es traducir y luego pedir la reapertura. Sin embargo, es una pregunta que pide recomendación de librerías y/o algoritmos, que es otro motivo de cierre.

Comment: Eso es raro. Supongo que no fue tu caso, pero habitualmente cuando se edita una pregunta cerrada, esta es enviada a una cola de revision especial. Quiza nadie decidio reabrirla por que no se solucionaron todos los motivos de cierre.